# Why is rstrip() not removing \n

Tags: python

```
def fixData(lib):
        for bookData in lib:
            for dataElement in bookData:
                if dataelement.endswith("\n"):
                     dataElement.rstrip("\n")
        return lib
```

Answer (score 8):

`rstrip` returns a new string, it does not mutate the existing string. So instead you could assign back over the string.

```
dataElement = dataElement.rstrip("\n")
```